# If an autocloseable is not stored in a variable, then do I have to try-with-resource it?

Tags: java, autocloseable

Saying I have an autocloseable resource (returned by a Sql.query call), then is it mandatory to put its return into a variable and try-with-resource it to avoid resource leaking?

```
    try (final Sql sql = ...) {
            // sql.query instanciates a java.sql.ResultSet and returns it
            sql.query("SET @x := 1");
    }
```

In such case, is it mandatory to change this code to:

```
    try (final Sql sql = ...) {
            // sql.query instanciates a java.sql.ResultSet and returns it
            try (final ResultSet useless = sql.query("SET @x := 1")) {}
    }
```

To avoid having a non-closed `java.sql.ResultSet`? I find no clear documentation about that case... I guess it should be, but I find no clear documentation about it (and since it feels strangely heavy, I'm not sure it's actually required)

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it is possible that your cursors may remain open on the database, and you'll eventually run out of connections.

Comment: Ok, I had a doubt since IntelliJ reports a `try (final ResultSet useless = sql.query("SET @x := 1")) {}` as having an unused variable and an empty `try` block (which should then be just a hint and not a warning)

Comment: @Xenos False positive.

Comment: @lexicore Alright, then I'll try these things even if the try block is empty, and put on a `SuppressWarning` on the 'false positives' about "empty try block"

Comment: @Xenos Also add a comment in the empty try block to explain why it is empty.

Comment: No, it isn't mandatory that you close that particular way, but it is mandatory that you close it somehow, and auto-close/try-with-resources is the most foolproof way.